# Search in specific country only?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, starting with the following query, I can pass user input to the Geocode API and return a json object/response with the locations details.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=10010
```

My problem is I have the following query with component filters with the country set to the US (United States). However, if you enter in a zipcode like this which is returning an area in Russia it still renders the map and sets the marker for the users current location.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=16721**&components=country:US**&sensor=false
```

Do I need to check the **short_name** within the returned object in a simple if statement and choose whether to issue a map request or not?

I thought component filters would restrict the user to search within the country specified? Then, return ZERO_RESULTS if there is not a match.

Any input, feedback is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Your [posted query](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=16721&components=country:US&sensor=false) returns a US address for me (in Kansas (37.09024,-95.712891) somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **stars** from from country name:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=16721**&sensor=false&components=country:US
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected. Not exactly the result I was hoping Google to return though. I thought Component Filtering allowed to return an error in the results object if the country was not matched.